# my php form have a three text box each text box have ID and Name

Tags: javascript, php, web

A form have a  three text box each text box have ID and Name. The ID and Names are dynamically created (like my student id is act as text box ID with the help of php. Name also from Database), Right now i need to calculate student marks from all the three boxes but the three box ID is dynamic now how to retrieve using java script?

```
<div style="clear:both;">
</div> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="<?php if(isset($cust_edit_val['itm_code'])){ echo $cust_edit_val['itm_code']."_itemname";}?>" style="border: 0px solid #505050; background-color:transparent;font-weight:bold; width:35%; float:left;" readonly=true value="<?php if(isset($cust_edit_val['item'])){echo $cust_edit_val['item'];}?>">
```

Comment: please post your form code

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: please set a class name for mark textbox. use the classname for calculating the sum

Comment: <div style="clear:both;"></div>        
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
        name="<?php if(isset($cust_edit_val['itm_code'])){echo $cust_edit_val['itm_code']."_itemname";}?>"
        style="border: 0px solid #505050; background-color:transparent;font-weight:bold; width:35%; float:left;"
        readonly=true value="<?php if(isset($cust_edit_val['item'])){echo $cust_edit_val['item'];}?>">

Comment: plz give some example Rakin

Comment: Edit your post and put your code there.. will be more helpful in getting an answer

Comment: please some one fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using only javascript

```
var val1 = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0].value;
var val2 = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[1].value;
var val3 = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[2].value;
alert(val1);
alert(val2);
alert(val3);
```

Will output the value of your input fields

Comment: it's not using bcz its working only first set of field

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan check updated answer. It will output all three input fields value which has class  `form-control`

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan Id of your input fields are dynamic but class are not dynamic right? Every input field has same class isn't it?

Comment: But, there are 50 students all records are listed one by one using while loop. okay . in your code working first row i mean first student . its not working in balance rows

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan loop through the array.you can see that index 1 collects the value of input 1 and it continues like that.

Comment: wait i will explain.. inside of while only three text box when loop is load based on database data automatically created textbox

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan please post all three input fields inside the loop